# How can I reliably set the class attr w/JavaScript on IE, FF, Chrome, etc.?

Tags: javascript, class, internet-explorer-7

I am using the below JS code in order to change the class when a link is clicked.

```
document.getElementById("gifts").setAttribute("class", "gkvSprite selected");
```

This is not working in IE but it does in FF and Chrome. Then I changed the code to:

```
document.getElementById("gifts").setAttribute("className", "gkvSprite selected");
```

Then it worked in IE, but stopped working in FF and Chrome.

Could someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Now that IE is well and truly gone, you can use `setAttribute("class", ___)` reliably.

Alternatively, you can reliably use the `className` property instead of `setAttribute`:

```
document.getElementById("gifts").className = "gkvSprite selected";
```

More generally, there are a couple of attribute names that IE (and only IE) got wrong with `setAttribute`: IE required `className` instead of `class`, and `htmlFor` instead of `for`. The reflected property names are `className` and `htmlFor`, but the *attribute* names are `class` and `for`, and `setAttribute` should be using the attribute names (and does, except on IE). (IIRC, IE11 fixed this, but it doesn't matter now that IE has been retired.)

Answer (score 2):

You can go about this in a few ways.

If you want to use `setAttribute` you can detect which browser the client is using and then use `class` in IE and `classname` in Firefox.

The above would work but I would prefer using a div and assigning a new class for that.

```
somediv.className='gkvSprite selected'
```

Or as T.J. Crowder said above. Asign via `Classname` directily.

Comment: Regarding detecting the browser: In at least 90% of these situations, you're much better off with "feature detection" rather than browser sniffing. In this case, for instance, Prototype checks whether the *actual browser you're using* uses `class` or `className` (by testing it once and remembering what happened). Browser sniffing is prone to failure in a variety of ways, not least getting outdated as browsers evolve. You end up with huge logic chains around browser and browser version...

Answer (score 0):

If #gifts has a timed CSS3 transition set on it in CSS, setAttribute (and removeAttribute, and other js commands) also fails in some browsers. The javascript must be delayed until the transition is done before it can modify it.