# I can't assign a class to an element opened in new window

Tags: javascript

hi every body I'm trying to open an image in a new window ,using javascript, by clicking on a button, then set a class to the image, using this code:

```
    OpenWindow=window.open("", "newwin","height=100,width=1000"); 
    OpenWindow.document.write("<img id='img1' src='webfonts.jpg'>");
    OpenWindow.document.getElementById("img1").className = "larger";
    OpenWindow.document.close();
```

and this is the internal style I have included in my code in a style tag:
.larger{ width:10px; }
and in the body tag 
1:I have include my image source by an img tag
2:make a button tag with an onclick=larger() attribute

but unfortunately I have a problem with last sentence, the class is not assigned at all to the image.
 I have tried to use classname also instead of setttribute but it generates the same result. 
any ideas?
thx

Comment: You forgot to include the code :)  Add it in, select it and click the 1's and 0's button to format it :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490627/how-can-i-reliably-set-the-class-attr-w-javascript-on-ie-ff-chrome-etc

Comment: and of course i have written the image source to the the new window by this line:
OpenWindow.document.write("<img ' src='webfonts.jpg'>") ;

Comment: You can edit your own question, you shouldn't post this in a comment.

Comment: this is the full code:
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>resize image </title>
<style>
.larger{ width:100px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function  larger()
    {
OpenWindow=window.open("", "newwin","height=100,width=1000"); 
OpenWindow.document.write("<img ' src='webfonts.jpg'>") ;
OpenWindow.document.getElementById("img1").setAttribute("class","larger");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="img1" src="webfonts.jpg"  border="0" />
<button   onclick="larger()">larger</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: the image is written to the new window successfully but the class is not assigned at all to it in the new window,instead it works on the image in the main page. u get it?

Comment: I have tried this also
<script type="text/javascript">
    function  larger()
    {
OpenWindow=window.open("", "newwin","height=100,width=1000"); 
OpenWindow.document.write("<img ' src='webfonts.jpg'>") ;
OpenWindow.document.getElementById("img1").className = "larger";
    }
</script>

Comment: I have tried to use classname instead of set attribute , but it generate the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the code you wrote is wrong. There's an apostrophe too much behind `img`.

Second, you didn't assign an ID to your `img` element, so you can't access it with `document.getElementById`.

Use something like

```
var docHead = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"'+
    'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'+
    '<html><head><title>Test page</title>'+
    '<style type="text/css">'+
    '  .larger { width: 10px }'+
    '</style></head><body>';
var docFoot = '</body></html>';

OpenWindow=window.open("", "newwin", "height=100,width=1000");
OpenWindow.document.write(docHead);
OpenWindow.document.write('<img id="img1" src="webfonts.jpg">');
OpenWindow.document.write(docFoot);
OpenWindow.document.close();
OpenWindow.document.getElementById('img1').className = "larger";
```

Comment: plz reread the code I have assigned an id to my image:
<img id="img1" src="webfonts.jpg"  border="0" />
in the body

Comment: but it doesn't work also, listen it seems to be better if i send u an attached file, but I am a new user, could u plz tell me how to do this.

Comment: I use fire fox 3.6.8 on windows platform

Comment: @loll – This *is* my code; I just surrounded it with `<script>` tags in an HTML file and ran it. The window appeared and checking with Firebug revealed that the class name was indeed set to ‘larger’.

Comment: and the image has been re sized to have a width=1000px? this my problem the class has no effect on the image size.

Comment: but if u rried this document.getElementById("img1").className = "larger"; (with out OpenWindow) the image will be resized successfully in the main page.

Comment: document.getElementById("img1").className = "larger";

Comment: @loll – That's a completely different problem. Did you embed a style sheet in the new window? The code above doesn't. I'll rework it a bit.

Comment: yes I have embedded an internal style using this line code:<style>.larger{ width:10px; }</style>

Comment: @loll – It's not in your code above. Perhaps you embedded it to the page that opens the new window, but you have to embed it there, too. See my revised answer.

Comment: aha ok I'll try it immediately

Comment: YES That's it, t finally works successfully thaaaaaaaaaaanks alot

Comment: @scunliffe – Thanks for editing, but in HTML 4.01 (the OP didn't specify the version and variant he's using) the end tag of the `img` element is [forbidden](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.2). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, you will also want to include in this new page some css otherwise this class="larger" will not do anything.

```
OpenWindow.document.write('<html><link href="css/style.css"/><body>');
OpenWindow.document.write('<img src="{source URL}" id="img1" class="larger" />');
OpenWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
```

Comment: first of all thanks a lot for your fast response, but i have included the class as internal style in my page this is the full code:
<style>
.larger{ width:1000px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function  larger()
    {
  OpenWindow.document.write('<html><body>');
OpenWindow.document.write('<img src="webfonts.jpg" id="img1" class="larger" />');
OpenWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
 }
</script>
<body>
<img id="img1" src="webfonts.jpg"  border="0" />
<button   onclick="larger()">larger</button>
</body>

Comment: <body>
<img id="img1" src="webfonts.jpg"  border="0" />
<button   onclick="larger()">larger</button>
</body>

Comment: <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>resize image </title>
<style>
.larger{ width:1000px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function  larger()
    {
  OpenWindow.document.write('<html><body>');
OpenWindow.document.write('<img src="webfonts.jpg" id="img1" class="larger" />');
OpenWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="img1" src="webfonts.jpg"  border="0" />
<button   onclick="larger()">larger</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: As others have noted, please update the code in the original question - trying to assemble 12 separate code fragments is very difficult

Comment: I have updated my question, but unfortunately it isnt allowed to add this code as new user :
and this my code in body tag:
<body>
<img id="img1" src="webfonts.jpg"  border="0" />
<button   onclick="larger()">larger</button>
</body>

Comment: <body>
<img id="img1" src="webfonts.jpg"  border="0" />
<button   onclick="larger()">larger</button>
</body>

Comment: the image is opened successfully in the new window but the class is not working at all