# Javascript - getElementById returning null despite elements with given IDs existing on page

Tags: javascript, css, setattribute, getattribute

I am writing a number of functions to show and hide various divs on a page by applying style classes called "hidden" and "visible" using setAttribute. This function is intended to hide several divs at once. The ID of each div to be given the class "hidden" is listed in an array.

Each div may have more than one class, so when a div is given the "hidden" class, it's other class(es) must be preserved, except for the "visible" class being replaced.

```js
function hideSections() {
  // Initialise array with div IDs
  var divs = new Array("tab-1", "tab-2", "tab-3", "tab-4", "tab-5");

  // Loop through divs in array
  for (var count = 0; count < divs.length; count++) {

    // Get existing classes
    var div = document.getElementById(divs[count]);
    var divClass = div.getAttribute("class");

    // Remove "visible" class if it exists
    divClass = divClass.replace("visible", "");

    // Append "hidden" class
    div.setAttribute("class", divClass + " hidden");
  }
}
```

For some reason this function is not working, though it is definitely being called.

An alert() placed inside the loop appears, if placed before the line [[var divClass = div.getAttribute("class");]]. Placed after this line, it does not, so I'm guessing this line is where the problem is.

All the divs have a class attribute specified.

Comment: any reason why your not using jQuery (http://jquery.com/)?

Comment: @Simon I started out trying to use jquery ui, but the tabs feature is being added to a page that requires and old version of jquery for its fancyboxes to work and jquery ui tabs don't display properly with the existing styles for this site.

Comment: If `getElementById()` doesn't find an element it will return null, which would then cause the next line to break. Put `alert(div);` and `alert(div.id);` before the line you've identified as the problem line so that you can confirm that you are finding the element. On jQuery: even an old version will be able to do this kind of simple select elements and change their class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reliably set the class attr w/JavaScript on IE, FF, Chrome, etc.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490627/how-can-i-reliably-set-the-class-attr-w-javascript-on-ie-ff-chrome-etc)

Comment: When is the function being called?

Comment: @nnnnnn It seems you're right. It turns out alert(document.getElementById("tabs-1")) gives me null, but I don't understand why because there's a div with that id on the page... Confused!

Comment: Look at the duplicate link I posted, it has the solution

Comment: Is it "tabs-1" or "tab-1"? In your comment there's an "s" but in the code in your question there isn't an "s". (Maybe you should post a small sample of your HTML?)

Comment: @spartanmouse this sort of thing is fundamental jQuery (manipulating attribute values) so will be available in an old version...something as simple as `$("div[id^='tab-']").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");` should get you pretty close. That basically selects all divs whose id starts with 'tab-' and removes the 'visible' class and adds the 'hidden' class.

Comment: @epascarello This is a different issue. The link you posted is to do with the way you set the class attribute in differnt browsers. The error in my function occurs before I get or set the class(es). In retrospect, mention of the setting of classes was a distraction from the real problem, which is to do with the getElementById line. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have elements which don't have a class attribute so `divClass` is null - causing an error on line `divClass = divClass.replace("visible", "");`. (can't call a method off a null value)

Try checking for the attribute:

```
  // Initialise array with div IDs
  var divs = new Array("tab-1", "tab-2", "tab-3", "tab-4", "tab-5");

  // Loop through divs in array
  for (var count = 0; count < divs.length; count++) {

    // Get existing classes
    var div = document.getElementById(divs[count]);
    var divClass = '';
    if(divClass = div.getAttribute("class")) {
        // Remove "visible" class if it exists
        divClass = divClass.replace("visible", "");
    }

    // Append "hidden" class
    div.setAttribute("class", divClass + " hidden");
  }
```

... or you can check out [the JSFiddle demo I created](http://jsfiddle.net/hcwTx/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but all divs have a class attribute specified, as stated in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

What you need are utility functions to add and remove classes. Here's some I use:

```
var trim = function(s) {
  return s.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
}

var hasClassName = function(el, cName) {
    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)');
    return el && re.test(el.className);
}

var addClassName = function(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    if (!hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        el.className = trim(el.className + ' ' + cName);
    }
}

var removeClassName = function(el, cName) {

    if (typeof el == 'string') el = document.getElementById(el);

    if (hasClassName(el, cName)) {
        var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + cName + '(\\s+|$)','g');
        el.className = trim(el.className.replace(re, ''));
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
addClass(elementOrId, 'classValue');
```

Wrap in a "namespace" or whatever suits.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    function hideSections() {
    // Initialise array with div IDs
    var divs = ["tab-1", "tab-2", "tab-3", "tab-4", "tab-5"];

    // Loop through divs in array
    for (var count = 0; count < divs.length; count++) {

        // Get existing classes
        var div = document.getElementById(divs[count]);
        var divClass = div.getAttribute("class");

        // Remove "visible" class if it exists
        var regex = new RegExp( '(?:^|\\s+)' + 'visible' + '(?=\\s|$)', 'i' );
        if ( regex.test( divClass ) ) {
            divClass = divClass.replace( regex, '' ).replace( /^\s+/, '' );

            // Append "hidden" class
            if ( divClass )
                div.setAttribute( 'class', divClass + ' hidden' );
            else
                div.setAttribute( 'class', 'hidden' );
        }

    }
}
```

Also you can try this out from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atma/5pJxT/1/)