# Apply css style to jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a jquery treeview plugin for my current project. Plugin can run well with firefox at this moment; however, when running with IE, all the css style cannot be applied. For example, i define in the css file #button {...}, then when i generate the control with id="button", it cannot retrieve the style from the css. How can i solve this issue ?

This is some of my codes

In the js file

```
    createControls = function() {

    nDiv = document.createElement("div");       
    nTxt = document.createElement("input");
    nTxt.setAttribute('id','txtAdVal');
    nTxt.setAttribute('type','text');
    nTxt.setAttribute('style' , "width:300px");

    nBut = document.createElement("button");
    nBut.innerHTML = "Show Active Directory Tree";
    nBut.setAttribute("class", "button");

    nDiv.appendChild(nTxt);
    nDiv.appendChild(nBut);

    $(nBut).bind('click', function(event) {
        createTree();
    });

    return nDiv;
};
```

and in the css file

```
.button{...}
```

Comment: Can you post your code and related information?

Comment: Edit that into your question. Also, format your code. Highlight it and press `Ctrl+K`.

Comment: sorry, not very familiar with the comment system here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about changing:

```
nBut.setAttribute("class", "button");
```

To:

```
nBut.className = "button";
```

Since you are already including jQuery you can also make sure you are doing everything cross-platform:

```
nBut = $("<button class='button'>Show Active Directory Tree</button>");
nDiv.append(nBut);
```

Note that this requires `nDiv` to be a jQuery object (`nDiv = $('div')`).

I found this answer on stackoverflow: [How can I reliably set the class attr w/JavaScript on IE, FF, Chrome, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490627/how-can-i-reliably-set-the-class-attr-w-javascript-on-ie-ff-chrome-etc)

Comment: Hmm somehow I doubt not using the jQuery method of changing an element's class would fix anything.

Comment: @jli Before I started to use jQuery I used `className` and never had an issue.

Comment: Awesome ! It works with className property. I also have some places with the setAttribute ('id', '...') and it still cannot work with IE. Is there the workaround way with the id value ?

Comment: @bubuzzz nBut.id = '<ID>';` should work fine. Or if you are trying to add an ID to a jQuery object then: `nBut[0].id = '<ID>';` OR `nBut.attr('id', '<ID>');`. The main point is that `<element>.id` works in all modern browsers so you don't have to resort to using jQuery's `.attr()` if you don't want to.